# com.ibm.sec.iam.platform.spi.PlatformException: CTJSO1119E in Bluemix

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

While configuring SSO Services in Bluemix, I'm getting the below error.

> com.ibm.sec.iam.platform.spi.PlatformException: CTJSO1119E The service
>   has reached maximum capacity. Please try again at a later time.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message states, the Single Sign On service has reached capacity. The service team is aware of the issue and is attempting to free up space. Please return to the service in a few hours. We apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Just for information - i have enough spaces and used less no. of services in my bluemix, then why i'm getting this error?

Comment: @Sabthosh Raj - The issue is currently with the number of instances across the Bluemix platform that are using the Single Sign On service; not with your specific environment.